# PHP post variable and array to Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, post

i've this two fields:

```
<input type="text" name="smsText" value="text sms to send to all">
<input type="text" name="recipients[]" value="3471234567">
<input type="text" name="recipients[]" value="3359876543">
<input type="text" name="recipients[]" value="3201472583">
```

And I need to send to a php page with an ajax call.

I've this function that i use in many scripts

```
$("#sendSms").click(function(){
    var text = $("input[name=smsText]").val();
    var recipients = $("input[name=recipients]").val();
     var datastr ='text=' + text +'&recipients=' + recipients;
    $(over).appendTo('#box');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send-result.php",
        data: datastr,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $('#box').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Please, i need help to modify my function to send both "smsText" and array recipients[] to other php page via Ajax...

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, if u want to use 'post' method u must form the argument list like `data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }`...hope it will help u...       `$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});` see the examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your following code:

```
var recipients = $("input[name=recipients]").val();
var datastr ='text=' + text +'&recipients=' + recipients;
```

for this one:

```
var datastr = '';
$("input[name='recipients[]']").each(function() {
    datastr += '&recipients[]=' + $(this).val();
});
datastr ='text=' + text + datastr;
```

that should do what you want and cause PHP to create the array variable `$_POST['recipients']` with all your values in it.

Comment: This line `datastr += '&recipients[]=' + $(this).val();` would concatenate `&recipients[]=` several times, thats not required.

Comment: @coder1984 You are wrong, it's required if you want PHP to create an array variable for all the individual `recipients[]` values.

Comment: @Nelson: perfect! This did the trick! Thank you very much to you and to the all others!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at jQuerys functions .serializeArray() and .serialize()

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var datastr = '&recipients[]=';
var arr = [];
$("input[name='recipients[]']").each(function() {
  arr[] = $(this).val();
});

datastr ='text=' + text + datastr + arr;
```

Comment: Your code is invalid javascript `Error:
Problem at line 10 character 7: Expected an identifier and instead saw ']'.
arr[] = $(this).val();`

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are contained within a form, you can use jQuery's serialize() method to convert the fields into a string to send via Ajax

```
<form id="sms-form">
    <input type="text" name="smsText" value="text sms to send to all">
    <input type="text" name="recipients[]" value="3471234567">
    <input type="text" name="recipients[]" value="3359876543">
    <input type="text" name="recipients[]" value="3201472583">
</form>

$("#sendSms").click(function(){
    var datastr = $("form#sms-form").serialize();
    $(over).appendTo('#box');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send-result.php",
        data: datastr,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $('#box').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

**html**

```
 <form name='ohForm' action="#">

     <input type="text" name="smsText" value="text sms to send to all">
     <input type="text" name="recipients[]" value="3471234567">
     <input type="text" name="recipients[]" value="3359876543">
     <input type="text" name="recipients[]" value="3201472583">
     // and others components

 </form>
```

**javascript**

```
          $("#sendSms").click(function(){
                var form = $("form[name='ohForm']");
                var datastr = form.serialize();
                $(over).appendTo('#box');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "send-result.php",
                    data: datastr,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data){
                     $('#box').html(data);
                    }
               });
        return false;
    });
```

**php**

```
         print_r($_POST['data']);
```